# Selecting data from two tables

Tags: mysql, command

Hello everybody
Well my question is about sql commands...

If I have 2 tables with the same number of columns and the same fieldnames (e.g: A(n,name,date) and B(n,name,date))

In the website, I want to retrieve data from both tables and display them in order by date descendent.

(The use of two tables is due to difference in tables database or server,or just the use of every table.. sometimes there's a need to display both tables in one order)

exemple

table Sport_news(N_event,Title,Texte,Date)
table International_news(N_event,Title,Texte,Date)

> Display:
>
> ```
>   Christiano Ronaldo ... 2011/25/01
>         christiano ronaldo is one of the famous...
>
>
>   Barack Obama president of the USA...  2011/24/01
>           Barak obama........
>
>   The arsenal has... 2011/23/01
>          Chamakh, player of arsenal is anger.....
> ```

I hope that the idea is clear : and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want UNION

```
select a.name,a.date
  from table1 a
 where ...
 UNION ALL
select b.name,b.date
  from table2 b
 where ...
order by 2 desc
```

When you use a UNION, you specify the order by with column *numbers* instead of names.

Comment: downs, thank you, even if I didn't try this(it's only a question I have all the time)... but it appears so clear and logic . +1 :-)